# how to run bash inside python loop

Tags: python, bash, loops, parsing

I have two files as below and I want to loop over the two files to create different combinations based on line in each file then input them as `i` and `j` to bash script in python:

file1

```
aaaa
tttt
cccc
gggg
```

file2

```
gggg
tttt
aaaa
cccc
ssss
```

I want to loop on the two files and then input them to a `bash` script. so every combination of `i` and `j` should be an input for `bash` script:

```
f1=[]
f2=[]
file1=open('file1.txt','r')
file2=open('file2.txt','r')

for i in file1:
    f1.append(i)

for j in file2:
    f2.append(j)

for i in f1:
    for j in f2:
        print(i)
        print(j)

bashscript i j
```

Comment: Use os.system() or subprocess.call() to execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [subprocess.run()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) or [subprocess.check_output()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)
depending whether you need to simply run the script, or if you want the output to be returned in Python.

Here a silly example

**bash_example.sh** is

```
echo 'Hello from Bash'
```

From within python:

```
from subprocess import check_output

check_output('bash bash_example.sh', shell=True)
b'Hello from Bash\n'
```

Comment: If you are explicitly running Bash anyway, `shell=True` is pretty silly (you are creating _three_ shells to execute _one_ `echo`).  Probably try `check_output(['bash', 'bash_example.sh'])` though of course if the Bash script is properly executable, you can just `check_output(['bash_example.sh'])`. What's probably more interesting to the OP is how to pass Python variables as arguments to the script, but this is obviously a common duplicate.

Comment: @tripleee You are right. I often use `shell=True` to avoid passing a list instead of a string to `check_output` and `run`.